# How to create transfer hook program for an existing Token-22 Program?

Tags: token-2022

I am new to token-22 and hoping someone can help me out. I recently launched a token-22 program on Fluxbeam using the transfer tax extension. Unfortunately, they don't give the ability to also add a transfer hook extension to extend customizations. My goal is to create a transfer hook that automates the process of converting the transer tax collected to Sol (or other tokens) either when a certain amount is collected or at a specific time interval. I am currently doing this manually but would like to automate with transfer hook if possible.

Is it possible to create a transfer hook program that I can connect to my existing fluxbeam token-22 program? If so, what are the next best steps?

Thanks,
Tarchie

Answer (score 2):

Once a token mint is initialized, it's not possible to add a transfer hook. Almost all extensions must be configured prior to initialization.

But once you're ready to create your next token, you can learn more about it at https://spl.solana.com/transfer-hook-interface and then start with the example transfer hook program at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/transfer-hook/example -- have fun!